# Sum of finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of series
$\frac{8}{5} + \frac{16}{65} + ....+\frac{128}{2^{18}+1} $ is

A) $\frac{540}{1088}$

B) $\frac{1088}{545}$

C) $\frac{1001}{500}$

D) $\frac{1013}{545}$

I am unable to figure out the general term of series. The answer given is B. How to figure out the general term and solve the question?

What kind of series is this, is it AP, GP, AGP, or combination of these or neither of these?

**I want answer till end, because some of answers below only generalized the series but I have no idea to sum that.**

Comment: The series has only five terms. You can work this put directly.

Comment: @Allawonder, smart man, I would rather leave the question in exam rather than computing it

Comment: Not even if you had a calculator, and all you need do is multiply the denominators and notice which of the options is a factor of this product?

Comment: Is this meant to be a finite (presumably five-term) sum, or an *infinite series*, with more terms after the $128/(2^{18}+1)$?

Comment: @Barry, only 5 terms

Comment: @Usercomingsoon, in that case something is off here. The missing terms would seem to be $32/(2^{10}+1)$ and $64/(2^{14}+1)$, but I don't get $1088/545$ from them; I get something with a much messier denominator.

Comment: @Allawonder - But what are the denominators? What are the terms? That's what the question is about.

Comment: @mr_e_man The pattern of the terms is easy to figure out. That's not what the question is about.

Comment: @mr_e_man You mean none of the denominators in the options divides $5×65×1025×(2^{14}+1)×(2^{18}+1)$? If this is in fact the case, then there's something wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

- Numerator terms get multiplied by $2$ every time.
- Denominator $5 = 2^2+1$ and $65 = 2^6+1$

Comment: Alright, But how would you solve it, I mean I only know ap, gp, agp to solve. But this thing looks like $\frac{8(2^{r-1})}{2^{4r-2}+1}$